# Display Google maps based on a city name

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm a newbie to the Google Maps. 
I have a city name in a php variable `$cityname`.

I want to display the Google maps for that city name. How can I make an API request to draw the google maps? I only know how to draw it using the latitude and longitude values.

Something like this: `var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(40.782865, -73.965355)`.
How can I just use the geocoding method? Something like this and to draw the map.

`http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example can be useful for you:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

You should pass the proper `address` value to geocoder

```
var address = <?php echo $cityname; ?>
```

Geocoder retrieves latitude and longitude values (see `results[0].geometry.location`). Then you can display the map by using them (i.e. setting center and marker).

Hope it helps.